# Assumption of polynomial

Tags: functions, polynomials, functional-equations, functional-inequalities

> Let $f(x)$ satisfy the equation
> $$f^2(x)=1+xf(x+1)$$ and the inequality $$x+1<2f(x)<4(x+1)$$ for all $x>1$. Find $f(x)$.  Here, $f^2(x)$ is $\big(f(x)\big)^2$.

I tried with assuming polynomial, but of no help. Is assuming polynomial correct?

If $f(x)=x+1$, then
$$f^2(x)=(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1=1+x(x+2)=1+xf(x+1).$$
When $x>1$, we have $x+1>0$, so
$$x+1<2(x+1)<4(x+1)$$
is true.  Therefore, $f(x)=x+1$ is a solution.  Are there other solutions?

Comment: Of course you can't assume $f(x)$ is polynomial unless you can prove that is indeed the case!

Comment: If $f(x)=x+1$, then both
$x+1<2f(x)<4(x+1)$ and
$f^2(x)=1+xf(x+1)$ are true...

Comment: @YiFan I don't understand your reasoning : a functional equation can have different solutions, and among them polynomials. Nothing illogical to look for if there exists such polynomial

Comment: I want not to assume anything.

Comment: @JeanMarie of course, but it will not give one all solutions for $f(x)$ and so does not solve the problem (unless of course it can be proven that the required $f(x)$ is indeed polynomial).

Comment: Is $f^2(x)= f(f(x))$ or $f(x)^2$?

Comment: A detail : Is the condition for all $x>1$ or for all $x>-1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a **unique** polynomial solution to the functional equation

$$f^2(x)=1+xf(x+1)\tag{1}$$

It is :

> $$f(x)=x+1 \tag{2}$$

(moreover compatible with the given inequations).

**Existence :** Let us look for a (at most) first degree polynomial solutions $f(x)=ax+b$ ($a$ can be zero).

$$(ax+b)^2=1+x(a(x+1)+b)$$

Expanding, one obtains :

$$a^2x+2abx+b^2=ax^2+(a+b)x+1 \ \ \iff  \ \ \begin{cases}a^2&=&a\\2ab&=&a+b\\b^2&=&1\end{cases}$$

The first equation has solutions $a=0$ or $a=1$. The case $a=0$ has to be excluded because it gives a contradiction with the other equations (we would have $b=0$ and $b=1$ !).

Therefore, plugging $a=1$ into the other equations gives $b=1$, and we have obtained solution (2).

**Unicity:** No other polynomial solution $f(x)=ax^n+...$ with a higher degree (i.e., $n>1$) can exist. Two reasons for that:

- The functional equation would have a LHS beginning by $a^2 x^{2n}$ whereas the RHS would begin by $ax^{n+1}$ : impossible for $n>1$.
- The inequations couldn't hold, knowing the growth of a polynomial with a degree $n$ higher than $1$ (imagine for example graphically a parabola "confined" between a pair of non vertical lines).

---

**Edit** : it remains to know if there are other (non polynomial) solutions.

We can look for them under the form :

$$f(x)=x+1+u(x)\tag{3}$$

with $u$ is non identically $0$ (we exploit here the particular solution we have found).

Plugging (3) into (1), we get :

$$(x+1+u(x))^2=1+x(x+2+u(x+1))$$

and finally :

$$\dfrac{u(x+1)}{u(x)}=\frac{u(x)}{x}+\frac{2}{x}+2\tag{4}$$

with the accompanying condition

$$-\frac12(x+1)<u(x)<x+1\tag{5}$$

We can  obtain a contradiction with $u \neq 0$ by considering a non-zero value $u(x_0)$. Due to condition (5), (4) gives

$$\left|\dfrac{u(x_0+n+1)}{u(x_0+n)}\right|>\dfrac{3}{2}+\dfrac{2}{x_0+n}$$

providing an exponential growth for the sequence $u(x_0+n)$ in contradiction with (5).

Warning : we have assumed implicitly that all values $u(x_0+n)$ are non zero. A rigorous argument is needed for proving that $x_0$ can be chosen in this way.